# Issue with Context Menu in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

While debugging in Visual Studio 2013, i'm facing an issue with context menu while right click on the `Error List`, where the context menu couldn't closed, it is displayed even over the browser.

[image]

How to resolve this issue.

Note : Migrated from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31018641/issue-with-context-menu-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: Does killing dwm.exe from Task Manager clears the menu?